# MongoDBCompass shell explain does not honor verbosity parameter

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, mongodb-compass, mongodb-explain

Using:  MongoDB 4.2.3 Community edition and the MongoSH Beta

When I run explain on an aggregate query, I get the queryPlanner output regardless of what I supply for the verbose parameter.

Ex:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{$match: {
  "entry.active" : true
}}]).explain("executionStats")
```

returns

```
{ queryPlanner: 
   { plannerVersion: 1,
     namespace: 'myDb.myCollection',
     indexFilterSet: false,
     parsedQuery: { 'entry.active': { '$eq': true } },
     queryHash: '53DDBAB6',
     planCacheKey: '53DDBAB6',
     optimizedPipeline: true,
     winningPlan: 
      { stage: 'COLLSCAN',
        filter: { 'entry.active': { '$eq': true } },
        direction: 'forward' },
     rejectedPlans: [] },
  serverInfo: 
   { host: 'zzzzz',
     port: 11111,
     version: '4.2.3',
     gitVersion: '6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4' },
  ok: 1 }
```

The output is the same whether I supply "executionStats", "allPlansExecution", or true as the parameter to explain.

Is there some way I can get the more verbose explain details for an aggregate query in Compass?

Comment: What does the documentation say about this?

Comment: mea culpa.  I was looking at the docs for cursor.explain (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#cursor.explain)  


But the aggregate docs (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) DO specify  


```You also cannot specify the explain option.```  


So I suppose that answers my question

Answer (score 1):

The explain parameter in aggregation pipelines is documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/) and it only has a boolean value (explain or don't explain).

There is no provision as far as I can tell to obtain execution stats from aggregation pipeline explains.

For comparison, the explain verbosity for non-aggregation explain is documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/explain/).

My guess is, because aggregation pipeline can contain multiple stages, the execution statistics aren't presentable as easily as they would be for what essentially is a single-stage find, so this functionality wasn't implemented.

Comment: Correct--I confirmed with mongo support rep yesterday that the more detailed execution stats for aggregation pipelines is an open feature request.

Answer (score 0):

After D.SM's question, I realized I was looking the cursor.explain docs instead of the aggregate.explain docs.  The latter explicitly state

***You also cannot specify the explain option.***

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate

Comment: That pertains to transactions. You can explain aggregation pipelines but you don't get execution stats as far as I can tell.